# SQL Server - Execute Stored Procedure Only Role

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

How do I create a custom SQL Server database server role that can only run `SELECT` queries and stored procedures?

Meaning, users of this role won't be allowed to do custom queries, but can run stored procedures that has CRUD and SysAdmin statements -- UPDATES, DELETES, ALTERS, DROPS.

I tried creating this custom role, but failed when I ran an SP that alters a table.

```
CREATE ROLE SupportStaff
GRANT SELECT TO SupportStaff
GRANT EXECUTE TO SupportStaff
```

Any ideas?

### Update

Okay, so I found that the above code allows Stored Procedures with INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. But it doesn't allow ALTER, TRUNCATE or DROP INDEX statements.

For ALTER, I simply need to add `GRANT ALTER TO SupportStaff`

But what do I need to do to allow `TRUNCATE` and `DROP INDEX`?

Comment: When you ran the updates, were you logged on as SA or someone from the dbo group? You can't alter a table you don't have ownership of.

Comment: I tested with a new SQL Login and added this role "SupportStaff" to this new user.

Comment: Hi Brian, I updated my question. GRANT ALTER allows me to alter a table, wonder if you know how to also allow TRUNCATE and DROP INDEX?

Comment: Alter should work for drop index and truncate, based on what I've read. Good luck ... It's friday and I'm heading home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a role and make it member of db_datareader then add EXECUTE permission to each procedure individually. Example with an user called test and member of that role. Run this as an admin:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE INSERTtest
AS
begin
INSERT INTO dbo.test
        (id)
VALUES
        (1)
END
GO  

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.INSERTtest TO test
GO
```

If your procs inset data into the tables, and they don't break the object's ownership chain, you should be fine with this set up. Try this with the user:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.test --sucess
INSERT INTO dbo.test(id)VALUES(1) -- fail
EXEC INSERTtest  --sucess
```