# T-SQL Allow users to only execute stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

For my database assignment I have to allow users to only execute stored procedures.

I know how to allow a user to only execute a single stored procedure but not all within the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Execute Stored Procedure Only Role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17745236/sql-server-execute-stored-procedure-only-role)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, that is for a single procedure, i need to know how to for all procedures in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new role give that role execute permission. You could also grant execute to a user but I assumed since you said "users" it would be easier to manage with a role.

```
CREATE ROLE Some_Role
GRANT EXECUTE TO Some_Role
```